# ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/opt/frontend/package.json'

Tags: docker

Dockerfile

```
# Dockerfile
FROM node:12.11.1

# update and install dependency
RUN apt-get update

# copy / target Main Folder
COPY . /opt/frontend

# work in folder
WORKDIR /opt/frontend

# install dependency
RUN npm install

# set app serving to permissive / assigned
# if you do not specify host, you cannot connect from the host
ENV HOST 0.0.0.0

# output port
EXPOSE 3000

CMD [ "npm", "run", "dev" ]
```

Error:

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path /opt/frontend/package.json
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/opt/frontend/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2021-11-15T14_31_01_250Z-debug.log
```

the build was succesful and read about this error that is package.json is not copy over, but isit this line already copy the main frontend folder everything over ?

```
# copy / target Main Folder
COPY . /opt/frontend
```

what i missout ? my github : https://github.com/differentMonster/nuxt3-troisjs

Comment: What command do you run for docker build? I'm which directory?

Comment: i run the build and run command on docker/dev/Dockerfile, i was trying to test it isolation first before docker-compose.

Comment: I'm asking because your build context may not be what you intend to be. I mean you're `COPY`ing `.` into `/opt/frontend` but that `.` may not include your `package.json` file.

Comment: humm isit the . mean everything with the folder ? and it will include my package.json as well ?

Comment: `.` means your current folder.

Comment: so as my current folder mean my frontend folder right ? or i get it wrong it only copy the docker/dev/ folder. cause i use to run this docker code and the folder was copy over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your are building the image with wrong context.
Try this:

```sh
cd frontend
docker build . -f ./docker/dev/Dockerfile -t your_app_name
```

Or

```sh
docker build ./frontend -f ./docker/dev/Dockerfile -t your_app_name
```

You need to specify a context path

Comment: Yeah now it work, but isit if i run and build docker command inside the only dockerfile it will execution by recoginzation it ?